# Question about OR operation in fully homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

[This page](http://windowsontheory.org/2012/05/02/building-the-swiss-army-knife/) (which won't let me post a comment, sadly!) describes how the original FHE paper by Craig Gentry describes FHE.

(Other references to this stuff can be found on [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/are-there-simpler-fhe-methods-than-craig-gentrys-original-paper).)

It mentions that once you have your key (an array of bits) and your encrypted values (arrays of floats in the range of $-1$ to $1$, with as many entries as there are in the key), that you can do an OR operation by adding the floats of two encrypted values together, and then modding by $2$.

I seem to be hitting a counter example to this so I was wondering if anyone could point out where my problem is.

Let's say that we have a key size of $1$, where the key is $[1]$ and we have three encrypted bits:

- $A = 0.01$ (plain text was false)
- $B = -0.99$ (plain text was true)
- $C = 0.99$ (plain text was true).

If we want to compute $Y:=A \lor B \lor C$, ($\lor$ is logical "or"), we do this:

- $X := (A + B) \bmod 2$
- $Y := (X + C) \bmod 2$

When we actually do this, here's what we get:

- $X = (0.01 - 0.99) = -0.98$
- $Y = (-0.98 + 0.99) = 0.01$

If we decrypt the result $0.01$ by rounding it to the nearest integer and then taking the absolute value, we get $0$ (false).

However... false OR true OR true should be true.

Where did i mis-step?  Thanks!

Comment: It's the XOR operation (exclusive-or, i.e., mod-2 addition), not OR.  See the second paragraph of the post.

Comment: Oh goodness you are right! Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I would feel a bit silly about calling this an "answer"... maybe you can extract a more interesting question from all of this?

Comment: It solved my issue. Trying to work out AND now :p